# hibernate auditing with trigger

Tags: java, hibernate, audit

I'm using hibernate with jpa and i have implemented audit with postgres trigger.

In my source code i have used à listenner on preInsert, preUpdate and preDelete to create a revision. This revision is added only if the saved entity is annoted by custom @AuditedEntity

This revision line contain transactionId and all the modification in same transaction is logged into audit_revision_details with postgres triggers and with this mecanism i can retrieve all modifications done on an entity.

I have à User entity with @AuditedEntity annotation and in the user entity i have a RoleUser Set. When i'm change lastname of the user, all work fine, i have a revision line created in my audit_revision table and in audit_revision_details i can see the change.

But when i'm saving only element inside RoleUser (i'm saving a user and RoleUser is save with CascadeType.ALL), revision is not created in audit_revision because when i'm entering in preInsert/preDelete or preUpdate listener,  the saved entity is RoleUser and RoleUser is not annoted by @AuditedEntity because it's User that have this annotation.

One solution is to add à field in User entity that i always update, with this, i always save User entity and i'have my revision but it's not very clean.

Another one is to check if the entity is annoted by @AuditedEntity or entity_name is 'RoleUser' and i always create revision...but if i change my lastname at the same time i change a role, i risk to have 2 revision in bdd so i need to check if one exist before...

I don't want to use hibernate-envers ( and envers have the same problem...)

How can i tell hibernate to force the revision creation when i only change entity inside another one?

Does anyone have implement same things and can help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> One solution is to add à field in User entity that i always update, with this, i always save User entity and i'have my revision but it's not very clean.

I think that is going to be your only viable option, unless you can make all the *ToMany associations owned i.e. remove the `mappedBy` part.

By making the many side the owning side, Hibernate will treat an entity as dirty when the collection changes somehow, though I don't think that changes to the entities within the collection will cause the same. If you want that changes to the elements also cause the entity to be treated as dirty, you will have to use an `@ElementCollection`.

Overall, introducing a field on User like `modificationTimestamp` which you update is probably the easiest way to achieve this.

Comment: ok that was i supposed, but finally i have add @AuditableEntity on all entity and when i saved a RoleUser entity it add a line as i expected, and during insert i add on confict on ... do nothing to don't have duplicate line, and when i save User and RoleUSer in same transaction, i have two lines as i want, and when i m reading the history i merge the line with the same transactionId and it's seem to be ok for the moment.